# python virtaul environment not accessing system environment variable

Tags: python, python-os

My Django settings.py file is not referencing system environment variable.

When I run `os.path.abspath(os.environ['EMAIL_USER'])` inside python shell when my virtual environment is not active I get path to my User folder `'C:\\Users\\<Username>\\<my_email>'` but when I run `os.path.abspath(os.environ['EMAIL_USER'])` inside python shell when my virtual environment is active I get path to my project folder `'N:\\Projects\\recipe_app\\<my_email>'`

Can someone explain why this is happening and how can I make my virtual environment reference to system environment variable?

Comment: Try running `echo %EMAIL_USER%` in your command prompt

Comment: @MelvinAbraham that does get me `EMAIL_USER` from system environment